# Why is the result 2 after decrement and increment operations

Tags: java, increment, decrement, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

There's some code:

```
int a = 1111;
a = a-- - --a;
a = a++ + ++a;
```

I know about prefix and postfix operators. But could you please explain the order of operations perfoming in these expressions?

Comment: The two lines evaluates to `a = 1111 - 1109; a = 1111 + 1113;`

Answer (score 1):

Java is always left to right. So your code is:

```
a = 1111;
a = 1111 - 1109 //2

a = 1111;
a = 1111 + 1113 //2224

a = 1111;
a = 1111 - 1109 //2
a = 2 + 4 //6
```

Plain English translation:

```
a = a-- - --a
```

Take the value stored in `a`, later decrement the value, but do not change what's already stored, then subtract the current value of `a`, but just a moment before decrement it. Store the result in `a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    a = a-- - --a; //1111 - 1109 = 2
    a = a++ + ++a; // 2 + 4 = 6
```

first line: a-- is evaluated as 1111, then decremented to 1110, then --a decremented to 1109 and evaluated as 1109.

second line: a++ is evaluated as 2, then incremented to 3, then ++a incremented to 4 and evaluated as 4.